# What happens to existing shards when enabling Elasticsearch allocation awareness

Tags: elasticsearch

I am following the instructions in https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-advanced-node-scheduling.html#k8s-affinity-options to enable AZ-aware shard allocation on my Elasticsearch cluster.

The Elasticsearch cluster already exists and is not AZ aware, so my question is: what happens when I turn these settings on? Will data be automatically reallocated, or will only new shards be allocated?  Are there any other operational steps that I should be taking?

Answer (score 1):

They will be relocated , if the cluster got nodes and capacity in other AZ - or else those indices will turn yellow